# Customize CommonFileDialog to Folder and File Picker

Tags: c#, windows-api-code-pack

I'm trying to make a File and Folder dialog in C#. (Just a warning: I will downvote ALL `FolderBrowserDialog` suggestions. That dialog is an abomination of nature)

Currently I'm using the `CommonOpenFileDialog` found in the WindowsApiCodePack, which has the property `IsFolderPicker`, that makes the dialog a folder picker only.
But my users need to be able to select either a file or a folder.

So I'm looking for a dialog which lets me select both a file and a folder. The means doesn't matter. C#, WPF, WindowsApiCodePack, Ookii dialogs, C++, P/Invoke, Com+, Win32, VB etc...

I just need a control that let me select a file or a folder, that I can call from C#, and that has the default Windows OpenFileDialog look. Is this possible, and how?

Comment: Hmm, how would something that looks like an OpenFileDialog be able to select both files and folders? If you went to go inside a folder to select a file wouldn't it select the folder instead?

Comment: The same way a folder browser works. You double click the folder, and it navigates to that folder. You single click on a folder, click on the Open button (in the lower right corner), and it closes the dialog and returns the selected folder.

Answer (score 1):

I customized the `FolderBrowser` dialog a couple of years ago.
I made it display the input field where the user may specify a path without having to browse for it. I *think* that can be customized to show files as well as folders.

This is how I did the customization:

I used .NET Reflector to disassemble the code for `FolderBrowserDialog`. I saved the disassembled code as `MyFolderBrowserDialog`.

In the reflected code I found that `FolderBrowserDialog` calls the unmanaged windows function [`SHBrowseForFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762115%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which accepts a [`BROWSEINFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773205%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) struct as parameter. The `BROWSEINFO` struct has the `ulFlags` member which is a flags value that may be bitmasked to include the features you want to use.

In `MyFolderBrowserDialog` bitmasked `BIF_EDITBOX (0x00000010)` into the `ulFlags` to get the input field.

According to the documentation if you bitmask `BIF_BROWSEINCLUDEFILES (0x00004000)` into `ulFlags` it should include files as well as folders and thus solve your problem.

I haven't actually tried to get it to display files, but I think it may be worth a shot.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I see I had a mistake in my post. I wrote that I will downvote all FileBrowserDialogs, but I mean FolderBrowserDialog. I will NOT use the FolderBrowserDialog, even though I know that I can display files in it.

Comment: Why not build your own? We built one ourselves once using a `TreeView` and `FileSystemWatcher` to keep it up to date.

Comment: Because that would be reinventing the wheel. I don't want to spend time replicating the theme of Windows classic, 7 and 8 and do all the logic again. It's just one modification to an existing control..